# Evaluating and rounding a file of numbers in scientific form

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I have a file full of expressions like this:

> 0.100000000000000000000*10^(1) 0.000000000000000000000*10^(0)
>
> 0.911403977421716024142*10^(-15) 0.983917614423065751378*10^(-15)

and I would like to evaluate each term and round the value to 2 decimal points to get:

> 1.00 0.00
>
> 0.00 0.00

Using "bc -l" on each token seperated by white space would accomplish the first step, but I don't know how to do this. Moreover, there is the issue with rounding.

Any suggestions are welcome!

FYI: There are three types of lines in the file. Those which are empty, those which contain a single integer and those which are of the form demonstrated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substitute` feature with a `submatch` and `system` function like so:

```
%s/\([^ ]\+\)/\=system('printf "%.2f" $(echo "scale=2; ' . submatch(1) . '" | bc -l)')/g
```

- this performs a `s`ubstitute on whole file (`%`).
- `\([^ ]\+\)` - matches every string stream which doesn't contain `space`.
- Then we replace all occurrences with an expression `\=` that's after it.

  - `system()` runs shell script/command and returns it's output.
  - `printf "%.2f" $(echo "scale=2; ' . submatch(1) . '" | bc -l)` - `submatch(1)` returns result of our match - so every math expression and whole is processed as a shell command.